# Via ansible change password of non-root account using passwd command and picking old password from ansible files

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have got a lot of systems having a common username to login. The password is also same for most of the systems. I have 1 inventory file with all the systems. For the systems that have a different password, I have saved the password against the hostname, and for the remaining it is in the group_vars file.

In inventory file:

```
hostname1 ansible_ssh_pass=pass1
hostname2 ansible_ssh_pass=pass2
hostname3
hostname4
```

group_vars file:

```
ansible_user: someuser
ansible_ssh_pass: pass3
```

I do not have higher priviledges. From another thread I was able to figure out how to only use passwd to change the password, and not use other utilities.

```
shell: 'printf "%s\n" OldPass NewPass NewPass | passwd'
```

The passwd does not support the "-p" option.

I am trying to figure out a way to get the OldPass value from the same where ansible is picking it for each host so that I do not have to run this playbook n number of times, and manually put the OldPass in the shell command.

Please advice on how to proceed with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Not quite the same, but I've written a simmilar script in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45988965/change-linux-password-with-ansible-playbook-script/53449783#53449783

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables directly:

```
$ ansible -c local -m shell \
  -a "printf '%s\n' {{ ansible_ssh_pass }} {{ ansible_ssh_newpass }}" \
  --extra-vars="ansible_ssh_pass=oldpass ansible_ssh_newpass=newpass" \
  localhost
127.0.0.1 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
oldpass
newpass
```

In this example, the variables are fed to `ansible` from the command line, in your example, they would come from `group_vars`.

You can even define a default value and override it for specific systems:

```
$ ansible -c local -m shell \
  -a "printf '%s\n' {{ ansible_ssh_pass | default('otherpass') }} {{ ansible_ssh_newpass }}" \
  --extra-vars="ansible_ssh_newpass=newpass" \
  localhost
127.0.0.1 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
otherpass
newpass
```